# Could not install the pods after upgrading the react-native to latest version 0.61.5

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have updated my app from react-native 0.60.4 to 0.61.5 it is working fine android. but in ios, I can't install pods. while running pod install I am getting this issue which is given below.

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `FBReactNativeSpec (= 0.61.5)` depended upon by `React-CoreModules`
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27140#issuecomment-551087858)?

Comment: yes, I have tried it.but no use

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the podspec path manually?

```
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
```

What version of cocoapods are you on?

Try running a `pod install --repo-update` as well.

Comment: I am using 1.9.0.beta.2 version of cocoa pods

Comment: after using the above two lines I am again getting error like this.
[!] Unable to find a specification for `ReactCommon/turbomodule/core (= 0.61.5)` depended upon by `React-CoreModules`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have follow this link 
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/
Here you have to set your previous version of project and newest version in which you want to update.Please follow instructions carefully, it will help you to upgrade project and hope everything would be work...

Answer (score 1):

try

`pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"`

instead of

`pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"`

it seems it changed folders from `/Libraries` to `/React`.

Answer (score 0):

https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/ is your best friend unless you have other custom components or changes in your code that you are not sure of what changes to make.